# Logging in C printing to both stdout and stderr without duplicates

Tags: c, logging, stdout, stderr

I've implemented my own message logging functions for my C command line program, I want to be able to print Info messages to `stdout`, Error messages to `stderr`, and Warning messages to both without having duplicate messages if they output to the same location.

The Info and Error messages work fine, but for the Warning messages I have no idea how to efficiently check if stdout and stderr file streams point to the same output location. My code works, but I can't figure out why, because logically when stepping through the function it should produce duplicate entrys if `stdout` and `stderr` point to the same file.

I've checked when `stdout` and `stderr` have the same output file, they still produce different memory addresses in the pointers and `fileno(stdout)` and `fileno(stderr)` are different.

tl;dr I have code that works, but as far as I'm aware... it shouldn't. Can anyone help explain why it is working or does anyone know the correct way to solve this.

Edit: the way I'm calling the program is: `myProgram >out.lis 2>out.lis`

Edit 2: When calling like this it does produce duplicates: `myProgram >out.lis 2>&1`

My Code for the warning message:

```
/* Warning message, a unified function for printing warning messages */
/* Warning messages are printed to both the output log and the error log (if different) */
void warningMessage(char * msg) {
    if (isatty(fileno(stderr))) {
        /* Add color if printing to terminal */
        fprintf(stderr, "\033[0;31;43mWarning: \033[0;30;43m%s\033[39;49m\r\n", msg);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nWarning: %s\n", msg);

        if (isatty(fileno(stdout))) {
            fprintf(stdout, "\033[0;31;43mWarning: \033[0;30;43m%s\033[39;49m\r\n", msg);
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "\nWarning: %s\n", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

*Any other pointers about my code would be helpful as well! I've only recently started learning C!*

Comment: Your code (partially) works because if `isatty(fileno(stderr))` is "true" (which is the usual case) then you don't print to `stdout` at all. Your code will break if `stderr` is not connected to a terminal (but for example to a pipe) when you will print both to `stderr` *and* `stdout`.

Comment: FWIW, this is a pretty uncommon thing to do for command line tools, and might be surprising to users. I'd reconsider whether you want to do this at all. I think it's impossible in the general case: what if I let stdout go straight to the terminal, but redirected stderr through `cat`? Both lines would still go to the terminal but there's no way for your program to know.

Comment: And you can reliably and portably only check if both `stderr` and `stdout` are connected to a terminal. If neither of them are then there's no (portable) way to know if both are using the same pipe/file/etc.

Comment: Yeh, where I can't see it working is if i run my program using `myProgram >out.lis 2>out.lis` yet it doesn't duplicate?

Comment: `myProgram >out.lis 2>out.lis` is quite crucial information that should have been in the question itself. Only *one* redirection will actually write to the file, not both. If you redirect to two different files you will see duplicates.

Comment: Instead of `myProgram >out.lis 2>out.lis` you should write `myProgram >out.lis 2>&1`  This opens the file only once.

Comment: Ahh okay, I've tried it using @DavidG's method of calling the program `myProgram >out.lis 2>&1` and that does produce duplicates

Comment: @GTBebbo -- yes it makes duplicates, and that is better.  Try the other method, write a long line to stdout, flush, and then a short line to stderr.  You may be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is going to be fstat().

Get the fileno() for both (should be 1 and 2 respectively, but might differ for non-Unix OSes), pass these as the first parameter to fstat(), and compare the structures filled in as the second parameter.  I would expect exact matches if they output to the same place.  I could believe that might the timestamps might be different.

I'm afraid I can't tell you if MS-Windows has the same call or not, but it should have an equivalent.

Don't forget to flush appropriately.

### Edit:

The [answer by Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039597/logging-in-c-printing-to-both-stdout-and-stderr-without-duplicates/60039927#60039927) notes you only *need* to check two fields.  This is correct (except perhaps on some weird filesystems).

There are some weird things that can happen.  If there are two device nodes for the same device (as in /dev/tty1 and /dev/tty1_alternate pointing to the same device) then st_ino will not match but st_rdev will.  I would treat these as different, as the user is playing games with you.

It might also be good to try to check if the two opens are the same open.
(Dealing with the `myprogram >out 2>out` case.)
For this, you probably need to mess with some of the parameters and see if changing one changes the other.  Probably the fcntl() function, using F_GETFL and F_SETFL.

Comment: Awesome! After messing around with the `stat struct` I've managed to get it to work... and understand why! Checking `st_dev` and `st_ino` did the trick and even works for the `myprogram >out 2>out` case. Thanks @some-programmer-dude and @david-g

Comment: Understanding is good.  Be warned: I believe there are some filesystems that don't use guaranteed unique i-node numbers.  In some cases, the field may not be big enough.  In one case, it wasn't part of the design of the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

A mentioned in [the answer by David G.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039746/440558) you could use [`fstat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) to check where the file descriptors really write.

On a POSIX system you use the [`stat` structure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) members `st_dev` and `st_ino` to find out what files are used. If these two members are equal for both `stdout` and `stderr` then you're writing to the same file.

I also suggest you make this check only *once* early in your program. Redirection happens only once, and you don't need to check for it every time you want to write a message.